# SQL Server COLLATION on table name

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

For a SQL Server database with collation set to "Latin1_General_100_CS_AS" I want to run a query like:

`SELECT * FROM tableName`, only the table name in the database is called TableName.

`SELECT * FROM TableName` works fine

`SELECT * FROM tableName` gives error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name

How can I make the query case insensitive?

Comment: is there a reason why you're using that specific collation?  if you were using the default collation for sql server then the table name wouldn't be case sensative.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall reading somewhere that you cannot do this.

The system database tables are always case-sensitive. As far as I know, you cannot turn that feature off, and this is not affected by your own collation settings, either - the system catalog tables are handled differently.

What you can do, however, is create a synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM tableName FOR dbo.TableName
```

and then your select will work again. Of course, it's not practical to create synonym for every possible case of upper-/lower-case typing - but this might be a "quick fix" for the couple most burning issues....

Comment: Hey Marc I thought the same tables where case sensive when between `[]` but this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47292477/how-to-prevent-collation-affecting-table-names-in-sql-syntax/47292683#47292683) prove me wrong. Maybe with 7 year more experience you can give a light on that one.