# How to prevent collation affecting table names in SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, collation

Can someone explain how to protect *table names* from being subject to the collation settings?
I'm currently getting the error message:

```
(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'Dataarchive'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'MyDatabase.dbo.Dataarchive'.
```

From this SQL:

```
USE master;  
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase COLLATE Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS;
GO

USE MyDatabase
CREATE TABLE DataArchive (id INT);
GO

SELECT * FROM DataArchive; -- succeeds
SELECT * FROM dataArcHIVE; -- succeeds
SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[DataArchive]; -- succeeds
GO
SELECT * FROM Dataarchive; -- fails - interprets aa as special A character.
GO
SELECT * FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Dataarchive]; -- fails
GO

USE MASTER;
DROP DATABASE MyDatabase;
GO
```

I expected collation to apply to sorting my data, not to table names themselves.

**Background**

This situation has arisen because the customer was responsible for installing the SQL Server, and set the server collation to Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS, thus any database, by default has this collation (and we do not specifically set the collation of the Database when creating a new database through code/script). In this situation, I still did not expect that our *table names* would be interpreted differently at all. Meaning our only option is to force latin collation on the database and users can specify per-column collation if they want something different?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Dataarchvie;`  fails becasue you spell it wrong

Comment: Thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza - I'll update the SQL - it still fails even with the correct spelling :-)

Comment: How did you try the query?  `aa` is a digram in Danish. It's not the database collation that affects the name, most likely your client translates this to `å`. There was a similar question a couple of weeks ago and I couldn't believe that `aa` wasn't `aa`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I just test it. If you remove the COLLATION all 5 query run exactly the same

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my SQL install is UK English, and I ran this in my SQL Server Management Studio. (2012SP3). This error also happens when our ODBC connection (from a UK English locale Application) sends the same SQL statement via code.  Changing the database collation to Latin1_General_CI_AS allows the statement to run successfully!

Comment: using bracket on the create table didnt solve the issue neither if collate is Norwegian. I just test it :(

Comment: @GilesDMiddleton and your collation is Danish. Why use a *Danish* collation if your client is UK? SQL Server connections have a setting to auto-translate between codepages/collations. Perhaps this issue will be solved if you set Autotranslate to off? That may create other issues though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I try direct on the SQL Management Studio and same error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos good challenge - but the statement will also fail if the client is Norwegian, and the SQL sent is accidently lowercase aa instead of aA. AutoTranslate isn't something I've tried, but could be a possible solution. I can't find the option in SQLServer to test it out. So will have to try via code. Thanks

Comment: should you be just using the standard database collation and apply your locale collation when filtering string type fields?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Ideally, yes! I've added a background section to help explain why I am where I am. In this case, the 'standard database collation' (i.e. server default) was Norwegian!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think SQL Server before execute a query, check or compile it, for example it checks for table validation like this:

```
select *
from sys.objects
where name = N'Dataarchive'
```

That will have no result. instead for other modes that will return a result.
Because of this it will raise:

> Invalid object name 'Dataarchive'.

But you can check over `sys.object` with another `COLLATION` like this:

```
select *
from sys.objects
where name COLLATE latin1_General_CI_AI = N'Dataarchive'
```

That will have a result, AFAIK, You can't force SQL Server DBMS to do its check or compile like this.

---

BTW, You can get data of a table in that case - with using Dynamic SQL - like this:

```
declare @tablename nvarchar(255) = 'Dataarchive';
declare @sql nvarchar(255) = 
    N'SELECT * FROM '+ (
        select name 
        from sys.tables 
        where name = @tablename COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI);
exec sp_sqlexec @sql;
```

Comment: With the thousands of database statements I have, this is not a good solution for me. I admit it is A solution, but every single table and column select would need to go through this process as I can't predict what two characters might be translated by SQL Server for all possible database collations.